# electron-react sticky table header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, electron, jsx

I'm currently working on my first project with electron-react and redux. I generate tables dynamicly on incoming data. My columns width is momently dynamicly based on the biggest cell in that column.

```
export default class myTable extends React.Component {

sortTable(col) {
        const { tableHead } = this.props.tabledata
        const { tableBody } = this.props.tabledata
        const { DataType } = this.props.tabledata
        const { length } = tableBody.allKeys

        var str = col.target.id.split('_')
        var isSorted = (toSort) =>{
            for(let i = 0; i < length-1; i++ ){
                if(tableBody.byKey[tableBody.allKeys[i]][tableHead.byCol[toSort].name]  
                    > tableBody.byKey[tableBody.allKeys[i+1]][tableHead.byCol[toSort].name]){
                    return "INC"
                    break
                }

            }
            return "DEC"
        }

        this.props.sortTable(str[0], str[1], isSorted(str[1]))

    }


render(){
    //Basic inline CSS Block
    const th = {
        backgroundColor: "#8c918d",
        width: "auto",
        whiteSpace: "nowrap"
    }


    //Pulling varibles needed out of this.props.tabledata
    const { tableHead } = this.props.tabledata
    const { tableBody } = this.props.tabledata
    const { DataType } = this.props.tabledata

    //filling thead with tableHeader data from store.state -- dynamicly
    //if column != visible table head column will not be added
    const cols = tableHead.allCols
    const colItems = cols.map( (col) => {   
        if(tableHead.byCol[col].visibility){
            let uid = DataType + '_' + col
            return <th key ={col} id={uid} style={th} onClick={this.sortTable.bind(this)}> {tableHead.byCol[col].name} </th>
        }
    })

    //filling the body with data from store.state
    //if column != visible, col in body will not be added
    const row = tableBody.allKeys.map((allKey) =>{
        return(
                <tr key={allKey}>
                    {
                        cols.map((col,i) => {
                            if(tableHead.byCol[col].visibility){
                                return <td key={i+1}>{tableBody.byKey[allKey][tableHead.byCol[col].name]}</td>
                            }
                        })
                    }
                </tr>
            )
    })

    //returning JSX dynamic generated Table
    return(
        <div>
            <Table  bordered striped inverse reflow>
                <thead >
                    <tr >
                        {colItems}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {row}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>
        )
 }
   }
```

For my Table I use reactstrap and bootstrap 4 beta. So now I want to make the Header of each table stick to the top of the table if I scroll inside the table. Lets asume all tables got a height of 200px and my data to display would take 400px. So I want to the table head stick to the top. 
In my current view im displaying on the top a title followed by some meta data and 3 dynamic created tables. Looks fine, until I add so much data to my tables that I have to scroll and I can't fix the header to stick on the top. 
Maybe someone can help me/give me an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I allready said I'm using bootstrap4 Beta. After researching in the doc's I found the class sticky-top which does what i want! So if you have a simular problem, just use the class="sticky-top"! Careful it wont work in Edge and IE 11